# How can i fix this error? c# asp linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

A few minutes ago this part of my code was functional with success, few minutes after i see this when i compile the project

[image: Error image result]

And the code is:

```
    string Cat = ddlCategoria.SelectedValue;
    int? MaxIdCat = (from p in db.tblProducto
                     where p.IdCategoria == Cat
                     select p.IdProducto).Max() + 1;

    txtIdEmp.Text = Convert.ToString(MaxIdCat ?? +1);
```

Comment: please share the table structure and more details.so that we can try to solve. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure Cat is having value in variable and as well as in table. If that value is not existing in table you have to handle is null on the entire linq query.